# VueRouter is not working, how to solve this? VueRouter is not a constructor

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js

I am new to Vue with some nodejs backend experiance.
I'm having problem and keep getting an error:

"Uncaught TypeError: VueRouter is not a constructor".
This is my cod(app.js):

```
const routes=[
{ path:'/home', component: home },
{ path:'/zaposlenik', component: zaposlenik },
{path:'/department', component: department }
]



const route = new VueRouter({
routes
})

const app= new Vue({
router
}).$mount('#app')
```

My department.js looks like:

```
const department={template: '<h1>Ovo je odsjek</h1>'}
```

And of course, I have this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item m-1">
                <router-link class="btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" to="/home">Home</router-link>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item m-1">
                <router-link class="btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" to="/department">Odjel</router-link>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item m-1">
                <router-link class="btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" to="/zaposlenik">Zaposlenik</router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>


    </nav>

    <router-view></router-view>

</div>

<script src="variables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.0/axios.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
<script src="home.js"></script>
<script src="department.js"></script>
<script src="zaposlenik.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Can you help me, please?

Thank you in advance,

Vinko

Answer (score 7):

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes=[
{ path:'/home', component: home },
{ path:'/zaposlenik', component: zaposlenik },
{path:'/department', component: department }
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
   history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
   routes
})

createApp({}).use(router).mount('#app')
```

There you go!
From the documentation : [Getting started](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript)

Comment: Thank you! But now I'm getting this error: Uncaught Error: Provide the "history" option when calling "createRouter()": https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#history.
    at Object.createRouter (vue-router@4:2940:17)
    at app.js:11:25

Comment: I edited my answer but you should learn how to use properly the router from the documentation

Comment: I agree.. I should! Thank you very much.. But I'm still getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor

Comment: I'll show you how I do it, if it solves your problem please mark it as correct answer. I edited my answer, it works with vue.js 3

Comment: I'll marker it, of course! Now I'm getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: That last comment is of course a separate topic, relating to the difference between `require` and `import` syntax. TLDR; You need to replace import with require or setup Babel properly.

Comment: What @Alex said ^

Comment: @AlexScott how exactly should I use require for this?